# java code to assign two minutes as a time interval

Tags: java

```
String qtm = "00:02:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date d = null;
try 
{
  d =  formatter.parse(qtm);}
catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
} 
System.out.println(d);
```

this code gives me:-

> Thu Jan 01 00:02:00 IST 1970

in my program I want to keep a time quantum of 2 minutes for roundrobin algo, how can I do that?? please help me.
when I give

```
long curr= d.getTime();
system.out.println(d);
```

it gives the output:-

> -19500000

please tell me how to give just 2 minutes as an interval and to assign it to a variable....

Comment: where do u want to use this quantum ?

Comment: can't you check those millisecond value and run it?

Comment: that millisecond value wat I was getting ws wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem at the moment is that your `SimpleDateFormat` is in your local time zone, whereas `Date.getTime()` gives you the milliseconds since the Unix epoch in UTC.

You *can* fix this as:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

... and then use `getTime()` as before.

Ideally, it would be better to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or the Java 8 `java.time` package, both of which have a `Duration` type to represent this sort of value. Joda Time has a `PeriodFormatter` which could be used to parse this as a `Period` and convert that into a `Duration`, which is a bit long-winded, admittedly. I don't *see* a way of parsing straight to a `Duration` for either of them...

Comment: thank you for the code and explanation :) its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want two minutes then why not go for the milliseconds equivalent (120000L) ?
If you are planning to use it within a scheduled thread pool executor, you could use (2, TimeUnit.Seconds). 
IMHO, the solution really depends on what purpose you want to use it for.